# UIPopoverController too large and UIPickerView too small

Tags: ios, ipad, uipickerview, uipopovercontroller

I have a `UIPickerView` displayed inside a `UIPopoverController`.  The dimensions of the `UIPickerView` are: `320x216`.  For some reason, the `UIPickerView` seems to be ~3/5 of the proper height, and the `UIPopoverController` spans all the way down to the bottom of the screen.

Please see the code below.

Thanks!

```
self.picker = [[[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height+44, 320, 216)] autorelease];
self.picker.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
self.picker.delegate = self;
self.picker.dataSource = self;
self.picker.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
UIViewController *pickerController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[pickerController setView:self.picker];
UIPopoverController *pickerPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:pickerController];
[pickerPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
pickerPopover.delegate = self;
self.popover = pickerPopover;
[pickerController release];
[pickerPopover release];
```

Comment: Just for anyone googling on to this, don't forget you simply set the column height of a picker, with the delegate call ... -(CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView **rowHeightForComponent:** (NSInteger)component { return 30.0; } (don't forget <UIPickerViewDelegate> in your .h file!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason for the "squashed" picker view seems to be this line:

```
[pickerController setView:self.picker];
```

Instead, add the picker view as a subview:

```
[pickerController.view addSubview:picker];
```

Next, to fix the popover height, set `popoverContentSize` before presenting it:

```
pickerPopover.popoverContentSize = picker.frame.size;
```

Also, fix the picker view's frame from this:

```
CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height+44, 320, 216)
```

to this:

```
CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216)
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked!
Just a question - why does using `setView:` cause a problem?

Comment: That's another good question.  Not sure but looks like a problem with the picker view.