# How to remove the dark spot background behind the date picker in iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, datepicker

I developed an application for iPhone. I have ported this same app to iPad.

All the views are working perfectly.

But the date pickers have a long dark back ground around them.

It doesn't change even I changed size in size inspector of IB

How should i remove this dark spot?

[image: This is the image of my date picker]

Comment: umm... are you talking about removing the *gradient* that surrounds the date picker?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response
Problem solved..
By Un check the 'Auto Resize Subview' in attribute inspector.

Comment: Just so you know, according to the iOS HIG, you should *only* present UIDatePickers within a popover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved..
- By Un check the 'Auto Resize Subview' in attribute inspector. 
In Interface Builder

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[[datePicker.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
[datePicker setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response
Problem solved..
By Un check the 'Auto Resize Subview' in attribute inspector.

Comment: When I try this, the control disappears entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Hello Ur's Truly Prasad,

Better way to implement UIPickerView for that the there is two way to Display UIPicker view which is more prefrable

1) You can put subview over the UIAlertview 
    following code fot that.

```
self.actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                     destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [self.actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);

    self.pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];

    self.pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    self.pickerView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    self.pickerView.delegate = self;
    self.pickerView.dataSource = self;
    [self.actionSheet addSubview:self.pickerView];

    UIToolbar *controlToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, dateSheet.bounds.size.width, 44)];

    [controlToolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
    [controlToolBar sizeToFit];

    UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

    UIBarButtonItem * setButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Set" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(dismissDateSet)];
    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelButton)];

    [controlToolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer, cancelButton, setButton, nil] animated:NO];

    [self.actionSheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
    [self.actionSheet addSubview:controlToolBar];
    [self.actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [self.actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0 ,  20 , 320, 485)];
```

[More that you can go to refrence link here](http://sugartin.info/2012/01/19/uipickerview-actionsheet-customization-problem-solution/)

2) You can put subview over the UIPopview controller.
[and same question for the UIPickerview inside into UIPopovercontroller here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088902/uipopovercontroller-too-large-and-uipickerview-too-small)

Thanks and Regards,

Samuel.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response
Problem solved..
By Un check the 'Auto Resize Subview' in attribute inspector.