# Discarding picker iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview

Recently I've submitted an application to Apple and they told me that to show a UIPickerView in iPad I have to embed it into a Popover, so the discarding is as easy as touching outside of the Popover...

How I'm supposed to discard a UIPickerView with iPhone?

I don't want to push another view and then return to the initial view to make the selection because it would interrupt usability flow.

On my current implementation I'm showing the UIPickerView below the selection UITextField and discarding it with a UIButton... is this method correct?

Kind regards!

Comment: So you are clear on iPad, but want to know how to handle it on iPhone?

Comment: Yes, thats what I'm trying to know because UIPopovers can't be used on iPhone.

Comment: How are you trying to do it?  Are you just hiding it when you press the UIButton?  Any code for what you have tried?

Comment: Finally! I've found what I was looking for.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/5347703/1211760

Answer (score 0):

No, the correct method is precisely as Apple explained to you.  You need to put the UIPickerView -INSIDE- a UIPopover.  Below is a link to another question/answer that would be a good reference for you:

[UIPopoverController too large and UIPickerView too small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088902/uipopovercontroller-too-large-and-uipickerview-too-small)

Comment: Though it is hard to discern, seems like his question is actually about how to handle it on iPhone.

Comment: Yes, I know how to do it on iPad, but I can't find information on how it should be done on iPhone... thanks in advance